# Coincidence ... or not ... or both ... perhaps neither? Indian Skepticism & Doubting Thomas

Tags: doubt, thomas-apostle, inter-faith, buddhism

[Doubting Thomas (Apostle, Patron Saint of India)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_the_Apostle) was the naysayer who just wouldn't believe in the miracle that defines Christianity (the resurrection). There are paintings that depict the Apostle Thomas poking his finger (ouch!!) into the risen Christ's cruxifixion wounds, symbolizing the lack/absence of faith.

Many, many, years earlier, [Sanjaya Belatthiputta](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanjaya_Belatthiputta), an Indian ascetic was expounding a radical brand of skepticism (the five-fold denial, if you're interested) that took Buddhist skepticism and went to town with it. Rumors go that skepticism (*doubt* in all its forms) has Indian roots; at the very least, there's an uncertainty as to whence skepticism sprang from, Greece? India? Both? Neither?

Coincidence ... or not ... or both ... or neither?

Comment: There is no evidence in the original text of scripture that Thomas ever did respond to Jesus' words by a physical action. He certainly responded to the voice of the Lord in faith, saying 'My Lord and My God', John 20:28. I think the question needs more focus as I am uncertain whether it is asking a question about Hinduism, Buddhism or Skepticism. (It's definitely not a question about _Christianity_. ) The question is also inaccurate saying 'Thomas just wouldn't . . ' whereas Thomas _promptly did_, as soon as the Lord made Himself known.

Comment: So now you are suggesting Paul (not Thomas) 'lacked faith'. There is no 'link' between the three religions you mention. They are thoroughly incompatible with each other. And Christianity is firmly (and absolutely) founded upon the Hebrew scriptures, not based upon any other ideology found on this earth.

Comment: @NigelJ, *ignosce mihi*, my wires are crossed ... that's what 40 or so years in a war zone does that to you. I'm of course referring to *Thomas*, the doubtful Christian and not Paul . I was just wondering about Christianity's rep as a *faith* and yet ... miracles (as *evidence*)??? Then Sanjaya Belathiputta, who asks "what about evidence?"

Comment: I am a proud Indian and a simple Christian. I live in the Capital City surrounded by people of different faiths including Hinduism, Islam, Buddhism , Jainism and Sikhism. I have seen staunch believers of the respective religions, and seldom come across atheists or agnostics. It may be worth checking as to how many followers Sanjaya Belathiputta has today.

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan, sound advice, mon ami, sound advice. However, Sanjaya Belathiputta (*requiescat in pace*) would, I'm only guessing, rather have no one follow him than have a billion simian followers.  

Comment: Your appreciation ( ? ) is well- taken .Hope , by mentioning simian followers you are not hurting the religious sentiments of our Hindu brethren who believe that a battalion of simians led by Hanuman helped Shri Ram build a bridge to Lanka so as to redeem Sita. Pax Christi.

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan, you must watch more youtube videos ... but a response true to the spirit of skepticism, would be "I don't think so. I don't think in that way. I don't think otherwise. I don't think not. I don't think not not." *Pax vobis*.

Comment: Pax Vobiscum. Let Peace stay with you .

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that, for a Christian who holds the Scripture in high regard, the doubt which stands against faith has demonic rather than human origins:

> Now the serpent was more subtil than any beast of the field which the LORD God had made. And he said unto the woman, **Yea, hath God said, Ye shall not eat of every tree of the garden?** - Genesis 3:1

And this followed closely by:

> And the serpent said unto the woman, Ye shall not surely die: For God doth know that in the day ye eat thereof, then your eyes shall be opened, and ye shall be as gods, knowing good and evil. - Genesis 3:4-5

There has been implanted, in the very being of humanity, doubt regarding what God has actually said and doubt regarding God's character and intent.  Modern forms of formal skepticism are not the same as the doubt which stands against faith (which stands upon displayed evidence):

> The heavens declare the glory of God; and the firmament sheweth his handywork. Day unto day uttereth speech, and night unto night sheweth knowledge. There is no speech nor language, where their voice is not heard. Their line is gone out through all the earth, and their words to the end of the world. - Psalm 19:1-4a

Comment: Arigato gozaimus. What do you have to say to this "argument": Some apples are green. Ergo, some things are green. A car is a thing. Ergo, a car could be green. ??

Comment: @AgentSmith Some apples are green when unripe, ergo green cars are unripe.